# How to cancel my own test in-app-purchase transaction? (so I can test again)

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm implementing an in app purchase for an iPhone app.
All is good - store kit is very easy to use and everything is working after few hours of programming.

Problem is : my product is non consumable, thus once I bought it, the app store always says that I already have it and does not let me test the payment again, it just calls transaction restore method.

Again : it's a NON consumable product.

Anybody knows how can I delete my purchase of that product, so I can test the payment again?

(without registering new test account, or other funny workarounds)

Comment: I am also curious about this one ... googling

Comment: the only I see is to create as many test accounts in itunesconnect as times I want to test before launching  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want to do.  You might find [SimStoreKit](http://github.com/millenomi/simstorekit) useful for testing, but to do it with the real test store, I think you would have to create a new user.

Comment: That's a good hint ! I couldn't find any description of what simstorekit does, but the name implies what should do... definitely great link ! if it works well I guess might be the answer

Comment: There isn't much documentation, but it's a "simulated version of the iPhone's StoreKit, for testing store UIs on the iPhone Simulator, or even on device without having to set up IAP in Connect."  You define your products in a plist, set the ILSimSKProductsPlist environmental variable, and #define ILSimReplaceRealStoreKit if you want it to replace the SK* classes with ILSimSK* ones.

Comment: I'm testing the SimStoreKit for few days now. Runs like a charm on the Simulator (Emanuelle already fixed some stuff I reported), but still can't compile and run it on the device ... however looks good this far, but compile for the device is crucial for me

Answer (score -2):

1. Delete the app from your device
2. Run "Clean" from the Product menu in XCode
3. On your device, go to "Settings", "Store", "Apple ID", and Sign Out
4. Start your app again, since you're not signed in to any account, the previous in-app purchase will not be recognized and you'll be able to buy it/download it again with the same test user account

Comment: you can download the product again, but not pay for it again, please read again the question